# How to apply a responsive CSS height to an element using min/max-height and height?

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design

I'm trying to expand a [Dygraph](http://dygraphs.com/) to the maximum available dimensions of it's parent container.

Technically the graph is resizeable, either by using a re-rendering method or by specifying an absolute container like in [this](http://dygraphs.com/tests/resize.html) example.

Problem is, the plugin expects hardcoded values, otherwise it will calculate something arbitrary - see [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/dygraphs-users/o-R-VdRIg1k) link for explanation, which says:

```
  // For historical reasons, the 'width' and 'height' options trump all CSS
  // rules _except_ for an explicit 'width' or 'height' on the div.
  // As an added convenience, if the div has zero height (like <div></div> does
  // without any styles), then we use a default height/width.
```

I have been playing around with the following setup:

```
<div class="graph_wrap">
  <div class="graph_container">
     <!-- graph will be here -->
  </div>
</div>
```

I managed to stretch the graph **WIDTH** to 100% by setting this CSS:

```
html .ui-graph {
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 1px;
}
```

but without specifying a height, the plugin overrides my CSS and doing this:

```
html .ui-graph {
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 1px;
  /* height... */
  height: auto;
  max-height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}
```

does not work. Only if I add something like `height: 20em`, the plugin does not overwrite my set CSS.

**Question**:
Is there any CSS way using `min/max-height/height` (or other) to force the browser to expand to maximum height? Can't think of anything else.
does

Comment: which height do you like the graph to have? To you want it to be 100% of the browser client height? Update: I just re-read your question: you want the Graph to be 100% (height and width) of it's parent container. How do you set the size of `.graph_wrap`?

Comment: expanding to available dimensions would be nice. I can hardcode a value like 20em and change this with media queries but the graph will be inside a flexible grid (x*y), so scaling according to width would be nice.

Comment: You wrote "*or by specifying an absolute container*" you can insert an absolute container in your grid like this: http://jsfiddle.net/NicoO/7268J/  would this do what you need? Or do you need a value after all? If so, check out viewport units `vw` and `wh`. But those are not relative to your grid.

Comment: Where does `.ui-graph` come from? I don't see it in the examples, and it's not in your HTML snippet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to force the browser to maximum height. You can write css like

```
.max_width{
width: 100%;
}
```

this will make the container 100%.

But the height will be determined by the height of the elements inside.

This can be solved using javascript though.

Comment: I don't need max height, I need **A** height. See the trick with width. I'm setting `min-width:1px` which I guess causes the plugin to not override width and my `100%` is applied. For height this does not work, but I'd be happy having something similar, like setting `min-height:1px;height:auto` but this does not work = makes my graph 1px.

Comment: Try this. I hope this is what you are looking for?<!doctype html>
<html>
 <head>
  <style type="text/css">
   .box{
    border: solid black 1px;
    position: relative;
    width: 100px;  /* desired width */
   }
.box:before{
 content: "";
 display: block;
 padding-top: 100%;  /* initial ratio of 1:1*/
}

.content{
 position:  absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 right: 0;
}
  </style>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div class="box">
   <div class='content'>Height Equals Width</div> 
  </div>
 </body>
</html>

Comment: Missed some code in my previous comment. So I have deleted the old comment. This new comment has code that works. Hope it will solve your problem.

Comment: I had the pseudo idea, too while walking home. I will try and let you know if it works.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it multiple ways:

The way It looks like you are doing is having the graph stretch with the browser window.

```
height: 10vw; /* viewport width */
```

or

```
height: 10vh; /* viewport height*/
```

these are different, so experiment what you want. This will definitely resize it.

Answer (score 1):

In the [resize-to-browser example](http://dygraphs.com/tests/resize.html) you provided, the element is scaling to the parent container just as you wanted. You can then apply your sizing rules to the container (`#div_g`), not the graph itself.

In that example, adding this will make the graph scale with the browser height until it is 300px tall:

```
#div_g {
    max-height: 300px;
}
```

All of the graph generated elements are calculated with JavaScript. That's why CSS doesn't work for them. So style the container, and let the graph itself resize it to fill that container.

You should be able to use `position: relative;` instead of absolute, if you want your graph to be positioned with other elements.

---

> *"Is there any CSS way using min/max-height/height (or other) to force the browser to expand to maximum height? Can't think of anything else. does"*

Traditionally the height of the html document is the same height as what it contains, like any other block element. You can stretch this to fit the browser height using the following:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}
```